# resize jPanel on VLCJ fullscreen for controlsPanel

Tags: netbeans, resize, jpanel, fullscreen, vlcj

I am using netbeans to create a media player using vlcj-3.8.0.jar.Here is the source code for netbeans users,[vlcj gui netbeans based](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=94452979679813524764) just unzip and open project in netbeans(contains playlist, volume, plays in canvas)I know placing the whole code violates the SSCCE standards but it might be informative for others. Another reason is that if you are a netbeans user then running the code and finding the problem is very easy for you, u wont need to search the entire code. So my problem, all works fine but i am having problem when i toggle the fullscreen. The controlsPanel as you can see in the picture below wont resize and i dont how how to do it. I tried to put the panel in border layout but it messes everything inside it(i have jslider and jlabels inside it).

http://postimg.org/image/kcxuwgjgx/

Here is a code to toggle on and off for fullscreen, where
jPanel2: is in border layout that has canvas inside it,
controlsPanel: panel in absolute layout that has jslider and jlabels has properties i set through netbeans as horizonal size and vertical size as default, horizontal resizable as ticked

```
private void toggle_fullscreenMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                               
    if(fullscreen_check==1){
        controlPanel.setVisible(true);
        titlePanel.setVisible(false);

        mediaPlayer.setFullScreen(true);
        //at fullscreen the controlPanel should be resized horizontally to the end of the screen
        controlPanel.setPreferredSize((new Dimension(1200,100)));
        controlPanel.setSize((new Dimension(1200,100)));
        controlPanel.revalidate();
        //here is the problem:controlPanel stays the same...why??
        fullscreen_check=0;
    }
    else{
        mediaPlayer.setFullScreen(false);
        Dimension ss = new Dimension (10,10);
        jPanel2.setPreferredSize(ss);
        jPanel2.setSize(ss);        
        jPanel2.revalidate();
        fullscreen_check=1;
    }       
}  `
```

I tried to use the code:

```
controlPanel.setPrefferedSize((new Dimension(1200,900);
controlPanel.revalidate();
//OR:
controlPanel.setSize((new Dimension(1200,900);
controlPanel.revalidate();
```

but it wont work...any help or idea will be greatly appreciated!! If any of you guys tried my code and make the controlsPanel to be resized to full screen, i will be very grateful!!

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you post a short, self contained, correct (compilable), example (http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your layout problem so that people can actually run it.

Comment: @caprica thanx for the reply, this is my very first post so i ll keep it in my mind for upcoming pst.., i am facing the one and only problem, resize the controlsPanel to the fullscreen size. I placed the picture in the link above, i m sure you would understand why i want to resize it...i am willing to provide the source code if you like, take a look at this link. [vidPlayer link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=94452979679813524764), it will be removed after a week so plz help me out anyone

Comment: plz keep in mind that i have vlc path file as c:\program files\videolan\vlc which is of course 64bit, so open the project in netbeans and run it, it should work, if not add the jar files in libraries which is present inside the folder, if i missed some then download at this link [vlcj dependencies](http://capricasoftware.co.uk/downloads/vlcj/vlcj-3.8.0-dist.zip)

Comment: If you want help from the stackoverflow community, then you should post your entire question and minimal code that reproduces the problem here and not post stuff off-site that will disappear. If you want to make it easy for people to help you, then post some example code that people can run.